# What naming constraints apply to C# conditional compilation symbols?

Tags: c#, syntax, conditional-compilation

What rules apply to the names of conditional compilation symbols in C#?

I've consulted the [#define documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx), the [/define compiler switch documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx), and the [C# language specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691098(v=vs.71).aspx). The #define and /define docs just say that you can define a symbol name, and that symbol names don't conflict with variable names. The language spec says that there is a "conditional-symbol" token, but doesn't appear to comment on what constitutes a valid symbol token - I might not be looking in quite the right place?

- Can conditional compilation symbols begin with numbers?
- Can they contain special characters such as . (e.g. for use in a version-number-related symbol)? How about non-breaking spaces?
- How about characters like #, {}, []?

**EDIT**: a link to *authoritative documentation* would be useful

Comment: I can and will. But a link to authoritative documentation would be useful, since it seems to be hard to find. Surely this isn't undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Hydrargyrum Looks like someone beat me, slightly, with the answer, but here's the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029).

Comment: I have incorporated your comment into your question. Feel free to edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol definition can be found in section 2.5.1 of the spec:

> #### 2.5.1 Conditional compilation symbols
>
> The conditional compilation functionality provided by the `#if`, `#elif`, `#else`, and `#endif` directives is controlled through pre-processing expressions (§2.5.2) and conditional compilation symbols.
>
> *conditional-symbol*:
> Any *identifier-or-keyword* except `true` or `false`

This is reflected online in the [same section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and in the [grammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/aa664812%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) under §C.1.10, but note that the spec that's available online is for a very old version of the language and should not be used as a reference. You can find the latest available spec in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Specifications\1033 or for [download](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) (it's still C# 5.0 as of this writing, apparently).

The definition of *identifier-or-keyword* can be found in §B.1.6 Identifiers.

Comment: Ah, that's helpful. Googling "identifier-or-keyword" brings me to [Section 2.4.2: Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx), which contains the relevant grammatical definitions for *identifier-or-keyword*. And those are the rules I was looking for.

Comment: @Hydrargyrum: Great! I'll update my answer with the *identifier-or-keyword* definition (or, at least, a summary of it).